# After running $ rake, and avoid rake aborted! `block in <top (required)>'

Tags: ruby, rake

Following exercise at https://gitimmersion.com/lab_21.html inside folder lib I created two files:

a) hello.rb containing:

```
# Default is "World"
# Author: Jim Weirich (jim@somewhere.com)
name = ARGV.first || "World"
puts "Hello, #{name}!"
```

b) and Rakefile.rb containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -wKU

task :default => :run

task :run do
  require './lib/hello'
end
```

Did add and commit the changes for both files. After typing $ rake in Terminal, as per exercise structure - the output shall be:

```
Hello, World!
```

However instead below information does appear in Terminal:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ./lib/hello      
.../lib/Rakefile.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default => run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Would like to ask how to get desired output after running $ rake

Comment: What has that got to do with “output in git”?

Comment: @Guildenstern I would like to know how to complete that task/lab21 lesson as per given link. When you can help me to reframe the question you can help a lot. I am only starting to learn git, no experience in ruby.

Comment: The line of code (`require './lib/hello'`) that raises the error tries to load a Ruby file named `lib/hello.rb` but is unable to find that file. Perhaps the file does not exist, is named differently, or is placed in a different folder than expected. Check the full path to your rake file, where that `hello.rb` file placed.

Comment: @mairo Git is a version control system. Whilst you may indeed be *using* `git`, your question has got absolutely nothing to do with `git`. What you're looking at is console/terminal output, not "git output".

Comment: @spickermann and others thank you for corrections, I tried to reformulate the question. Regarding full path, I put them both in lib file, also tried to change from require './lib/hello' to require './lib/hello.rb'.

Comment: @TomLord thanks for corrections, I did edit the question, tried to formulate it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require './lib/hello'` expects to find:

***from your current directory, where you ran `rake`***

or ***a directory you added to your $PATH variable***,

a directory called `lib` that contains a file called `hello.rb`

What you need to determine is why `rake` isn't finding that file.

Let's say this is your file structure:

- /User

  - /gitimmersion

    - /lab_21

      - /lib

        - hello.rb

Running your code from any directory except /lab_21 will cause this error.

You can either change your directory in your terminal or change your `require` code to correctly traverse from your current directory to the directory where your `hello.rb` file is located.